# How to change font size of the annotation in seaborn jointplot?

Tags: python, annotations, font-size, seaborn

I am making a jointplot with a regression line using -

```
sns.jointplot(xdata,ydata,kind='reg', order=2,ylim=[-1,1],xlim=[-1,1],annot_kws={"loc": 4})
```

I can change the location using `annot_kws`, but cannot change the font size. How do I change the font size?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the font size by changing default legend fontsize for `matplotlib` before making the plot.

```
matplotlib.rc("legend", fontsize=20)
sns.jointplot(xdata,ydata,kind='reg', order=2,ylim=[-1,1],xlim=[-1,1],annot_kws={"loc": 4})
```